# Unable to connect with Secret ARN to Aurora Serverless

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

AM trying to access Aurora DB Cluster in AWS but getting the following error-

```
Sep 19, 2019 5:28:31 PM com.amazonaws.internal.DefaultServiceEndpointBuilder getServiceEndpoint
INFO: {rds-data, eu-west-1} was not found in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard pattern for this region: 'rds-data.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'.

com.amazonaws.services.rdsdata.model.BadRequestException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. (Service: AWSRDSData; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 3b6c5939-e88e-42f4-ba60-c28bb4e7c28f)
```

Aurora server-less is supported in the EU-West-1 region, so what is the issue here?
The secret ARN was created by AWS when I created a user using the Serverless Console. Is that not ok?

Answer (score 0):

Since it was in dev mode, the service is down when it gives this error. I had set a time interval of 5 minutes of inactivity to trigger a shutdown of the Aurora service. After the first request it takes a while to come up.  So we implemented a wait and retry loop to get around this issue.
In dev, we hit this issue when someone hits the DB first. 
Not an issue in production as the system is in use all the time, so DB is up.